# Using rank() in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have the following tables (simplified) in Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE party(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    family_name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE election(
    id int,
    country_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    e_type election_type NOT NULL,
    e_date date NOT NULL,
    vote_share numeric,
    seats int,
    seats_total int NOT NULL,
    party_name_short varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    party_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    party_name_english varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    party_id int REFERENCES party(id)
);
```

I like to know how a certain political party performs in elections. To do so I wrote a simple query:

```
SELECT
    e.country_name,
    extract(year FROM e.e_date) AS year,
    e.party_name,
    round(e.vote_share, 1) AS vote_share
FROM
    election e
    LEFT JOIN party p ON e.party_id = p.id
WHERE
    e.e_type = 'parliament'
    AND p.family_name IN ('Green/Ecologist')
    AND e.country_name = 'Luxembourg'
    AND e.e_date >= '1980-01-01'::date
    AND e.e_date < '2020-01-01'::date
GROUP BY
    e.country_name,
    e.e_date,
    e.party_name,
    e.vote_share
ORDER BY
    e.country_name,
    year;
```

This gives the following result:

```
+------------+------+-----------------------------------+-----+
| Luxembourg | 1984 | Déi Gréng                         | 5.2 |
| Luxembourg | 1989 | Déi Gréng                         | 4.2 |
| Luxembourg | 1989 | Greng Lëscht Ekologesch Initiativ | 4.2 |
+------------+------+-----------------------------------+-----+
```

I'd like to add one more information: the rank of each political party in election as measured by its vote share. I can do this for a single election (see result below) but my code won't work for the above written query. Please find below my working query for single election:

```
SELECT
    extract(year FROM e.e_date) AS year,
    e.party_name,
    e.country_name,
    round(e.vote_share, 1) AS vote_share,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY e.id ORDER BY e.vote_share DESC) vote_rank_number
FROM
    election e
WHERE
    e.id = 1;
```

and the result:

```
+------+----------------------------------+-------------+------+---+
| 1972 | Labour Party                     | New Zealand | 48.4 | 1 |
| 1972 | National Party                   | New Zealand | 41.5 | 2 |
| 1972 | Social Credit | Democratic Party | New Zealand |  6.7 | 3 |
| 1972 | Values Party                     | New Zealand |  2.0 | 4 |
+------+----------------------------------+-------------+------+---+
```

I use Postgres 14 but I can install 15 if needed.

**UPDATE**

Please have a look at the **following data**. It shows election result for one year only. `Déi Gréng` ranks fourth in this election.

```
+------------+------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+------+
|  country   | year |                  party name                   |             party name original              | vote_share | rank |
+------------+------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| Luxembourg | 1984 | Chrëschtlech Sozial Vollekspartei             | Christian Social People's Party              |       34.9 |    1 |
| Luxembourg | 1984 | Lëtzebuerger Sozialistesch Aarbechterpartei   | Luxembourg Socialist Workers' Party          |       33.6 |    2 |
| Luxembourg | 1984 | Demokratesch Partei                           | Democratic Party                             |       18.7 |    3 |
| Luxembourg | 1984 | Déi Gréng                                     | The Greens                                   |        5.2 |    4 |
| Luxembourg | 1984 | Kommunistesch Partei Lëtzebuerg               | Communist Party of Luxembourg                |        5.0 |    5 |
| Luxembourg | 1984 | Jean Gremling List – Socialistes Indépendants | Jean Gremling List -- Independent Socialists |        2.5 |    6 |
+------------+------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+------+
```

No let's back to my initial query. Here I want to add rank().

```
SELECT
    e.country_name,
    extract(year FROM e.e_date) AS year,
    e.party_name,
    round(e.vote_share, 1) AS vote_share,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY e.id ORDER BY e.vote_share DESC) vote_rank_number
FROM
    election e
    LEFT JOIN party p ON e.party_id = p.id
WHERE
    e.e_type = 'parliament'
    AND p.family_name IN ('Green/Ecologist')
    AND e.country_name = 'Luxembourg'
    AND e.e_date >= '1980-01-01'::date
    AND e.e_date < '2020-01-01'::date
GROUP BY
    e.id,
    e.country_name,
    e.e_date,
    e.party_name,
    e.vote_share
ORDER BY
    e.country_name,
    year;
```

The query gives the following result:

```
+------------+------+-----------------------------------+------------+------+
|  country   | year |            party name             | vote_share | rank |
+------------+------+-----------------------------------+------------+------+
| Luxembourg | 1984 | Déi Gréng                         |        5.2 |    1 |
| Luxembourg | 1989 | Greng Lëscht Ekologesch Initiativ |        4.2 |    1 |
| Luxembourg | 1989 | Déi Gréng                         |        4.2 |    2 |
| Luxembourg | 1994 | Déi Gréng                         |       10.2 |    1 |
| Luxembourg | 1999 | Greng Lëscht Ekologesch Initiativ |        1.1 |    2 |
| Luxembourg | 1999 | Déi Gréng                         |        9.1 |    1 |
| Luxembourg | 2004 | Déi Gréng                         |       11.5 |    1 |
| Luxembourg | 2009 | Déi Gréng                         |       11.7 |    1 |
| Luxembourg | 2013 | Déi Gréng                         |       10.1 |    1 |
| Luxembourg | 2018 | Déi Gréng                         |       14.1 |    1 |
+------------+------+-----------------------------------+------------+------+
```

It wrongly outputs `1` for `1984` election year. It should be `4` as shown earlier. I hope I'm more clear know.

Comment: Can you add the expected output to your post?

Comment: The GROUP BY in your original query is redundant / unnecessary.  Could you take it off and retry the rank query?

Comment: @lemon Sure, I will do it.

Comment: The p.family_name condition in the WHERE clause makes your LEFT JOIN return regular INNER JOIN result. Move that condition to the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result. (Or switch to INNER JOIN if you want INNER JOIN result.)

Comment: @SGandhi I removed the `group by` but I still get the wrong results.

Comment: The problem here is that your ranking function activates after the aggregation has already been carried out. Something you could do is turning your aggregation into window functions, with the corresponding partitioning, and apply a `DISTINCT` on top of it: this should allow you to retrieve the content of the ranking before the aggregate operation. Afterwards, trying to simplify your code (it seems you're partioning on way more columns than you really need, and have some issues in your join operation, as per jarlh's comment).

Comment: @menteith could you explain the filter  AND p.family_name IN ('Green/Ecologist').  It looks like certain parties are being suppressed from the output.  Could this filter be causing the suppression of other parties?    The rank() will only work after the filter so will not be able to correctly rank() if certain parties are removed.

Comment: @SGandhi Political parties could be conservative, social democratic and green/ecological (and other too). I am interested in how green parties perform compared to other parties: conservative, social democratic and so on. Hence the filter `AND p.family_name IN ('Green/Ecologist')`.

Comment: But, by adding the filter you have removed the other parties like conservative and social democratic and they are no longer part of the ranking set.  If you need to correct rank across parties,  rank, you'll have to first write a query that gets you the rank and then nest it under another query on which you may apply the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT
    e.country_name,
    extract(year FROM e.e_date) AS year,
    e.party_name,
    p.family_name,
    round(e.vote_share, 1) AS vote_share,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY extract(year FROM e.e_date) ORDER BY e.vote_share DESC) AS vote_rank_number
FROM
    election e
    LEFT JOIN party p ON e.party_id = p.id
WHERE
    e.e_type = 'parliament'
    AND e.country_name = 'Luxembourg'
    AND e.e_date >= '1980-01-01'::date
    AND e.e_date < '2020-01-01'::date
ORDER BY
    e.country_name,
    year
) 

WHERE family_name IN ('Green/Ecologist')
```

Comment: It did the trick, thank you! I needed to add alias to sub query to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include rank of each political part's vote share in every election year, you can modify your query like this:

```
SELECT
    e.country_name,
    extract(year FROM e.e_date) AS year,
    e.party_name,
    round(e.vote_share, 1) AS vote_share,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY extract(year FROM e.e_date) ORDER BY e.vote_share DESC) AS vote_rank_number
FROM
    election e
    LEFT JOIN party p ON e.party_id = p.id
WHERE
    e.e_type = 'parliament'
    AND p.family_name IN ('Green/Ecologist')
    AND e.country_name = 'Luxembourg'
    AND e.e_date >= '1980-01-01'::date
    AND e.e_date < '2020-01-01'::date
GROUP BY
    e.country_name,
    extract(year FROM e.e_date),
    e.party_name,
    e.vote_share
ORDER BY
    e.country_name,
    year;
```

Comment: This query gives wrong results - exactly the same as mine query.